# Merge Two Arrays, one is sorted and the other one is not and the second doesn't fit into memory [Python]

Tags: python, algorithm, pointers, data-structures, merge

First question was to merge two sorted arrays. For that I used the 2 pointer approach.

```
class Solution(object):
    def merge(self, nums1, m, nums2, n):
        """
        :type nums1: List[int]
        :type m: int
        :type nums2: List[int]
        :type n: int
        :rtype: void Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.
        """
        # two get pointers for nums1 and nums2
        p1 = m - 1
        p2 = n - 1
        # set pointer for nums1
        p = m + n - 1

        # while there are still elements to compare
        while p1 >= 0 and p2 >= 0:
            if nums1[p1] < nums2[p2]:
                nums1[p] = nums2[p2]
                p2 -= 1
            else:
                nums1[p] =  nums1[p1]
                p1 -= 1
            p -= 1

        # add missing elements from nums2
        nums1[:p2 + 1] = nums2[:p2 + 1]
```

The approach above takes O(n+m) time and O(1) space since there is no extra copying to new array and instead we start to overwrite nums1 from the end, where there is no information yet. Then no additional space is needed.

**Now what if the first array is too big to fit into memory and is not sorted then output a sorted a array? What would the solution look like in that case?**

Comment: What would it even mean to "merge" an unsorted array with a sorted array? Is the result supposed to be sorted? If so, it's pretty much going to come down to an [external sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) of the unsorted array, and the sorted array is mostly a distraction.

Comment: Yes the result is supposed to be sorted @user2357112supportsMonica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External sort should solve this problem as suggested in the comment.